# How can I run a PHP mail() function without a user loading a page/.php file?

Tags: php, email

This is all of the code surrounding the section I'm asking about (see an abbreviated more to the point section below this one).

```
if($register == "true") //Registration "checks out" okay
        {
        $gooddata['password'] = md5($gooddata['password']);
//This is where the information is saved to the database.
            $query = "INSERT INTO member (username,password,votingdistrict,email,birthmonth,birthyear,city,state,zip5,registeredtovote)
                      VALUES ('$gooddata[username]','$gooddata[password]','$gooddata[votingdistrict]','$gooddata[email]','$gooddata[birthmonth]','$gooddata[birthyear]','$gooddata[city]','$gooddata[state]','$gooddata[zip5]','$gooddata[registeredtovote]')";

        $result = mysqli_query(dbcxn('member'),$query)
                or die("<h3 class=\"headertag\">Username or E-mail already exists. <a href=\"./register.php\">Try a different username</a> or <a href=\"./resetpassword.php\">reset your password</a></h3>\n</header>");
        if($result)
            {
            $query = "SELECT vernumber FROM member WHERE username='$gooddata[username]'";

            $result = mysqli_query(dbcxn('member'),$query)
                or die("Could not find a verification number!");
                if($result)
                    {
                    $preextract = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    extract($preextract);
                    $email = $gooddata['email'];
                    $subject = "Confirmation of Unipartisan registration for " . $gooddata['username'];
                    $message = wordwrap("Please click <a href=\"\">this link<a> to complete your registration.<br /> \n" . 
                               "If you did not try to register with <a href=\"http://unipartisan.com\">Unipartisan.com</a> please disregard this e-mail or click here.",70);
                    $mailsent = mail($email,$subject,$message);
                    if($mailsent == true)
                        {
                        echo "An e-mail has been sent to you to complete your registration</h3>\n";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            echo "The registration email failed to send</h3>\n";
                        }

                    }
            }        

        echo "</header>\n";
        echo "<article class=\"index\">\n";
        echo "    <h3>Return to the <a href=\"./index.php\">homepage</a></h3>\n";
        echo "</article>\n";           
        }
```

My question is how can I still send the user an e-mail after registration is completed successfully, but without doing it in the same .php file, and without having to send that .php file to the user.

The reason I am asking is because the mail() function takes a lot of time to process and the page wont load for roughly 30 seconds.  The email, however, does in fact get sent successfully.

Below is the specific section that I am referring to.

```
 $email = $gooddata['email'];
 $subject = "Confirmation of Unipartisan registration for " . $gooddata['username'];
 $message = wordwrap("Please click <a href=\"\">this link<a> to complete your registration.<br /> \n" . 
 "If you did not try to register with <a href=\"http://unipartisan.com\">Unipartisan.com</a> please disregard this e-mail or click here.",70);
$mailsent = mail($email,$subject,$message);
if($mailsent == true)
    {
    echo "An e-mail has been sent to you to complete your registration</h3>\n";
    }
```

I am aware that I can use cronjob for this, but I am only finding situations where programmers are attempting to set a repeated script by time, or they are attempting to delay a script.  I still want it to run immediately, but I do not want to run the mail function in the same file as the registration processing because it causes that ugly delay on the client side.

How can I do this contemporaneously with the completion of registration?

Here is the relevant section of my PHP.ini.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = ryan@unipartisan.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f ryan@unipartisan.com

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
```

Comment: "the mail() function takes a lot of time to process and the page wont load for roughly 30 seconds" --- that's weird. It should just transfer the data to MTA, instantly.

Comment: This MTA thing you speak of may be what's wrong.  I am using sendmail on Linux Mint 13, and I have set my PHP.ini mail path to /usr/sbin/sendmail.  I'll add my PHP.ini to the question.

Comment: I've been using postfix for donkeys years now and never had issues. It's much easier to configure than sendmail (install and it just works).  It might be easier to try postfix if you can.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the question anyway because I figured it out, but for some reason, this delay that I had no longer happens even without using this method and I don't know why for sure.  it is very possible that my ISP was being slow the other day, but zerkms said that it sends it to the MTA and it shouldn't have an effect on the loading of the PHP file anyway.  I don't know what's happening there.

Comment: I am beginning to think that installing postfix is what solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have written two files in php that show how this is done.  If there is no need for a delay or to run the file at intervals, then just use the terminal.

```
<!--File Name: cmdlinetest.php
This is the file that execute.php would run
-->
<?php
/*  
In the Unix terminal I can write: 

php /pathtophpfile/cmdlinetest.php MyEmail MyEmail'sDomain EmailSubjectorOtherVariable
```

1) So I am calling the program, php, and telling it to run cmdlinetest.php...

2)There is a space, and then I write the e-mail I want the .php file to handle the first part of my email: myemail

3)Then a space and the second part of my email: google.com

3)Then another space plus a username(or other desired variable) for my website, so I know what part of my database to handle.

4)The command line global variable $argv is passed into the .php file.

```
$argv[0] == "/pathtophpfile/cmdlinetest.php"//this is pretty much useless, so ignore it!
$argv[1] == "MyEmail"//no @ symbol.
$argv[2] == "MyEmail'sDomain"//no @ symbol.
$argv[3] == "EmailSubjectorOtherVariable"
```

What is basically happening is that it is passing each string separated by a space in the terminal command that 
comes AFTER "php" as an array value starting with 0.

To further clarify, if I add "EmailMessage" after "EmailSubjectorOtherVariable" and the command would look like this:

```
php /pathtophpfile/cmdlinetest.php MyEmail google.com EmailSubjectorOtherVariable EmailMessage
```

The program being called by the command: php

$argv[0]: The file's name so php knows what it's running, and it becoming the value for $argv[0] is merely a "side-effect" if you will...

$argv[1]: The first string separated by spaces after the file name which is my e-mail before the @ symbol.

$argv[2]: The second string separated by spaces which is my e-mail AFTER the @ symbol.

$argv[3]: The username for my website that I'm passing to the file incase I wanted to do database manipulation or an email subject let's say.

$argv[4]: Now that the last space-separated string in the terminal command is "EmailMessage"... you guessed it; $argv[4] == "EmailMessage"

**IF YOU PUT AN @ SIGN IN THE COMMAND IT WILL BREAK!!!!**

youremail@google.com must be put into two array keys as "youremail" and "google.com"
add the @ symbol in the php code!!

This is the error I got for adding the @ in the email:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '@' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/unipartisan/cmdlinetest.php on line 26
```

Now I will echo the passed variables for testing purposes.

```
echo "E-mail part 1: " . $argv[1] . "\nE-mail part 2: " . $argv[2] . "\n";//Key 1 has email before the @. Key 2 has after the @.

echo "Subject of e-mail(site's username): " . $argv[3] . "\n";//The username you want to test.  (This can really be anything you want; username is an example)

echo "Message of e-mail: " . $argv[4] . "\n"; //"EmailMessage"
```

The above echos are just to test your outputs for yourself.  The user won't see any of this when it is ran in another file in an exec() function

Now because the email is bifurcated we need to put it back together again!

```
$wholeemail = $argv[1] . '@' . $argv[2]; 

echo $wholeemail . "\n";
```

Another test for us humans to make sure it's right. The echos will show up if you run this from the terminal.

If it is ran in exec() in another .php file your users will not see it. So they only serve for testing while building THIS FILE!

Below I name the $argv keys in their own variable just to make this look less confusing for new people.

```
$subject = $argv[3];//Username or email subject
$message = $argv[4];//"EmailMessage"

mail($wholeemail,$subject,$message,"FROM: Unipartisan Registration");//"FROM: Who ever you are"
exit();
?>
```

That is where cmdlinetest.php ends.

This is where execute.php comes in.

```
<!--File Name: execute.php
This is an example of the code you would enter in the 
php file being displayed to the user when you want to run an 
external script without showing it to the user.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
exec('php /YourPathTo/cmdlinetest.php EmailBeforeAt EmailAfter@ YourEmailSubject YourMessage');//Abandon all hope ye who dare put an @ symbol here
echo "Okay go check your e-mail and hope it comes.";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Because I'm a nice guy, here is a simple version of cmdline.php without the excessive commenting.

```
<!--File Name: cmdline.php-->
<?php
echo "E-mail part 1: " . $argv[1] . "\nE-mail part 2: " . $argv[2] . "\n";//Key 1 has email before the @. Key 2 has after the @.
echo "Subject of e-mail(site's username): " . $argv[3] . "\n";//The username you want to test.  (This can really be anything you want; username is an example)
echo "Message of e-mail: " . $argv[4] . "\n"; //"EmailMessage"

$wholeemail = $argv[1] . '@' . $argv[2]; 

echo $wholeemail . "\n"; //Another test for us humans to make sure it's right.  The echos will show up if you run this from the terminal.
//If it is ran in exec() in another .php file your users will not see it. So they only serve for testing while building THIS FILE!

//Below I name the $argv keys in their own variable just to make this look less confusing for new people.
$subject = $argv[3];//Username or email subject
$message = $argv[4];//"EmailMessage"

mail($wholeemail,$subject,$message,"FROM: Something");//"FROM: Who ever you are!"
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I think you may be able to not bifurcate the e-mail as long as you escape the character with a \.  So if you have youremail@google.com Make sure to write youremail\@google.com.  If my subject is "Hello world"  Write: Hello\ World.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to separate this out, you could:

1. Create a new column in your user table named "welcomeEmailSent".  Set this as a bool, default 0.
2. Write a script named sendRegisterEmails.php.  This script should connect to the database and retrieve all rows that have welcomeEmailSent=0.
3. The script then loops through doing your mail() stuff for each pending user, and also updates the user table to mark welcomeEmailSent=1
4. set up a cron task to run the sendRegisterEmails.php script.

Type "crontab -e" and then add this line to run the command every 10 minutes.

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php5 /path/to/sendRegisterEmails.php
```

Make sure the path to your PHP is correct.

I would however try to work out why the mail() functionis taking so long, but this would be a quick fix for now.

Comment: The thing is I would expect this command to run as soon as someone registers.  If they were an unlucky one and have to wait 10 minutes, they may give up on the site completely.  I don't think cron is the solution I need.  My domain name has its e-mails handled by Google.  Does that give me other options?

Comment: If its your own server then just set the con job to to run every minute. If its on shared hosting it will usually limit you to minimum of 10 minute intervals.  If you've got MTA delays for whatever reason, and you need to bring the mail code out of the register script, then this is the only real way to do it... A task that runs in the background at small intervals.